# ROS Android Build Not Working

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed this: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform/Clients/Android
But get the following error when doing `rosmake android_app_chooser --threads=1`

> rosrun rosjava_bootstrap make.py android_gingerbread
> Buildfile: /home/turtlebot/ROS_DIR/rosjava_android/android_gingerbread/dependencies.xml

> get-dependencies:

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
> Total time: 11 seconds
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/turtlebot/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/make.py", line 108, in
> main(sys.argv)
> File "/home/turtlebot/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/make.py", line 100, in main
> build(rospack, package)
> File "/home/turtlebot/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/make.py", line 65, in build
> properties = android.generate_properties(rospack, package)
> File "/home/turtlebot/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/android.py", line 93, in generate_properties
> 'sdk.dir': get_android_sdk_dir(),
> File "/home/turtlebot/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/android.py", line 78, in get_android_sdk_dir
> location = which.which('android')
> File "/home/turtlebot/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/which.py", > line 248, in which
> raise WhichError("Could not find '%s' on the path." % command)
> which.WhichError: Could not find 'android' on the path.
> make: *** [all] Error 1

UPDATE:

I fixed the bash_profile and now I'm getting a new error, any help is appreciate!

> BUILD FAILED
> /home/turtlebot/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/android.xml:539: The following error occurred while executing this line:
> /home/turtlebot/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/android.xml:568: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/turtlebot/Desktop/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools/aapt": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:475)
> at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:610)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:827)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:445)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:459)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:635)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:676)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:502)
> at com.android.ant.AaptExecTask.callAapt(AaptExecTask.java:603)
> at com.android.ant.AaptExecTask.execute(AaptExecTask.java:351)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
> at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1360)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1329)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1212)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:801)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:218)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
> at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:164)
> at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81)
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:468)
> ... 47 more

Total time: 5 seconds
Executing command: ['ant']
make: *** [all] Error 1

I can see aapt is at /home/turtlebot/Desktop/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12713/ros-android-build-not-working/) by [Derek Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/1679/derek-lee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The build tools can't find the `android` command.

You need to install the android developer tools and make sure they are on your PATH. See [these instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform/Clients/Android#line-31) for a more detailed description of how to do this.

If you can't run `android` from a command prompt, the build tools won't be able to either.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-01-24**:
I saw your update; I don't have a good answer for you. It might be a permissions problem, or a broken symlink, or something else completely.

**Comment by [Derek Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/1679/derek-lee/) on 2012-01-24**:
I fix the first problem but having a new one right now, can you please help? Thanks.